# LVM and device mapper: Logical Volume device sector size

Tags: linux, partition, lvm, device-mapper, kpartx

This seems to be a problem regarding the sector size of the mapped device for a logical volume between different machines.

More specifically, I'd like to know if and how the sector size of a mapped device corresponding to a logical volume can be configured.

Here is a description of the problem, comparing two machines.

### Machine 1

I have an entire disk image in a logical volume `mytestlv` in a volume group named `MyVolumeGroup`.

This disk image has its own partition table (completely independent of the actual disk it's stored on).

For example, `fdisk /dev/mapper/MyVolumeGroup-mytestlv` shows this:

```
Disk /dev/mapper/MyVolumeGroup-mytestlv: 30 GiB, 32212254720 bytes, 62914560 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: ...

Device                                    Start      End  Sectors Size Type
/dev/mapper/MyVolumeGroup-mytestlv-part1    2048     4095     2048   1M BIOS boot
/dev/mapper/MyVolumeGroup-mytestlv-part2    4096  4198399  4194304   2G Linux swap
/dev/mapper/MyVolumeGroup-mytestlv-part3 4198400 62914526 58716127  28G Linux filesystem
```

If I need access to the data on a partition of that disk image, I can use `kpartx` and mount the partition.

`kpartx -a /dev/mapper/MyVolumeGroup-mytestlv` creates these devices files, which can be used to mount a partition within that disk image, for example:

```
/dev/mapper/MyVolumeGroup-mytestlvl
/dev/mapper/MyVolumeGroup-mytestlv2
/dev/mapper/MyVolumeGroup-mytestlv3
```

### Machine 2

This was now copied onto a different machine (content is exactly the same, checksums of both entire `/dev/mapper/MyVolumeGroup-mytestlv` are identical).

Using the configured block size, `fdisk /dev/mapper/MyVolumeGroup-mytestlv` shows this:

```
/dev/mapper/MyVolumeGroup-mytestlv: 30 GiB, 32212254720 bytes, 7864320 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device                                  Boot Start     End Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/mapper/MyVolumeGroup-mytestlv-part1          1 7864319 7864319  30G ee GPT
```

### Differences

The logical sector size is 512 on Machine 1, but 4096 on Machine 2.

On Machine 1, `blockdev --getss /dev/mapper/MyVolumeGroup-mytestlv` returns 512.

On Machine 2, `blockdev --getss /dev/mapper/MyVolumeGroup-mytestlv` returns 4096.

### Workaround

On Machine 2, forcing the sector size to 512 with `fdisk` helps it see the partition table correctly.

```bash
fdisk --sector-size 512 /dev/mapper/MyVolumeGroup-mytestlv
```

```
Disk /dev/mapper/MyVolumeGroup-mytestlv: 30 GiB, 32212254720 bytes, 62914560 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: ...

Device                                    Start      End  Sectors Size Type
/dev/mapper/MyVolumeGroup-mytestlv-part1    2048     4095     2048   1M BIOS boot
/dev/mapper/MyVolumeGroup-mytestlv-part2    4096  4198399  4194304   2G Linux swap
/dev/mapper/MyVolumeGroup-mytestlv-part3 4198400 62914526 58716127  28G Linux filesystem
```

Unfortunately, other tools such as `sfdisk` or `kpartx` don't seem to have those options.

If I create a loopback device explicitly from that LV, then that loopback device has a sector size of 512, and everything works (in fact, versions of `losetup` that are not too old have an explicit sector size option).
After `losetup --show -f /dev/mapper/MyVolumeGroup-mytestlv`:

- `blockdev --getss /dev/loop0` returns 512
- `kpartx -a /dev/loop0` creates `/dev/mapper/loop0p{1,2,3}`

### Where is that sector size configured?

I'd like to be able to use `fdisk`, `sfdisk`, `kpartx` without relying on an additional `losetup`.

On Machine 2, `cat /sys/block/dm-2/queue/hw_sector_size` returns 4096 (`/dev/mapper/MyVolumeGroup-mytestlv` is actually a soft-link to `/dev/dm-2`). I've tried to change this using `echo 512 > /sys/block/dm-2/queue/hw_sector_size`, but this doesn't seem to be possible.

- Is there a way to tell LVM that I'd like the sector size for the device corresponding to `/dev/mapper/MyVolumeGroup-mytestlv` to be 512?
- Is that something that affects all the logical volumes in the group or on the system?

I can't see any options with `lvcreate` or `lvdisplay` related to this.

Comment: Did you try lvchange -r ?

Comment: @admstg I've just tried `lvchange -r 512 /dev/mapper/MyVolumeGroup-mytestlv`.
It says: "*Command on LV MyVolumeGroup/mytestlv uses options that are invalid with LV properties: lv_is_thick_origin. Command not permitted on LV MyVolumeGroup/mytestlv.*". No change on `blockdev --getss`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default sector size comes from the underlying hardware, as far as I've understood it.

So on Machine 1, the underlying disks is/are apparently in [*Advanced Format 512e*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Format) mode, probably because Machine 1's disk controller is not capable of using 4k sectors natively. Another possibility is that on Machine 1, one of the physical volumes of `MyVolumeGroup` cannot support 4k sector size, and so the entire volume group must use the sector size that its least capable disk can support.

On the other hand, Machine 2 and all the physical volumes of its `MyVolumeGroup` seem to be fully capable of using 4k sector size natively (*Advanced Format 4Kn*). It defaults to doing so because that is way more efficient than emulating the old 512-byte sector size.